# How to get domains registered in Facebook using facebook-sdk-php-v4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Please let me know how to get domains registered in Facebook using facebook-sdk-php-v4. 
To get Facebook Pages I am using below code:
$my_accounts = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
This pulls up Facebook pages id and details which I can use to pull Facebook Insights.

How can I accomplish the same with Domains? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use FQL

```
SELECT domain_id FROM domain_admin WHERE owner_id =me()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: FQL is going away April 30th 2015, when API v1 is retired.